# Unable to use Restriction Rules on Financial Service Cloud?

Tags: licenses, userlicense, financial-services-cloud

I have created a trial org with Financial Service Cloud.
I am not able to see the permission required for creating Restriction Rules

Following is permission Name

"View Setup & Configuration AND View Restriction and Scoping Rules"

Please help

Comment: As per [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_restriction_rule.htm&type=5) restriction rules are `Available in: Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, and Developer Editions` . Please check the edition of your trail org.

Comment: Yes Swetha , my trial Org is a developer Edition only

Comment: Where and how are you trying to find/ assign these permissions ? Is it via permission set?

Comment: Both via Permission set or on Profile , i am not able to find View Restriction and Scoping Rules  Permission

Comment: Just FYI , created a different org , its showing this permission as well as Restriction rule on Task Object

Comment: And is the other org ,a trail edition too?

Answer (score 1):

You should able to see(View Setup and Configuration, View Restriction and Scoping Rules) under '**System Permissions**' on profile/permission set if you are signing up for trail version from [here](https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/financial-services-cloud-trial/) .

[image]

Please note restriction rules are available for custom objects, contracts, events, tasks, time sheets, and time sheet entries. Restriction rules aren’t available for external objects.

Thanks

Comment: hi @Vinay..That step has already been checked .The issue is when you sign up with Financial Service Cloud  Org , these Permission are not available

Comment: I am able to see under 'System Permissions' make sure you select license type as 'salesforce' when you are creating permission set in Developer edition.

Comment: Vinay are you using FSC developer org ? Also I did check using Salesforce as licensce  its not there in FSC Developer Edition Org

Comment: Yes,  you can sign up [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/promo/orgs/fscplayground)

Comment: Thats strange , if you try following   , you will not be able to see restriction rule. So wondering what is issue. Because same issue i am getting in my Sandbox
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/promo/orgs/fscspecialist

Comment: Just use above sent link and sign up for dev org.

Comment: That i got it , my main concern is what is missing... because we are using Financial Service Cloud Production Org as well as Sandbox in our Company  and we are not able to see Restriction rules in our respective Sandboxes

Answer (score 1):

I have the answer now , We have to raise a case. Salesforce Support team will enable some permission , post that we will be able to see Restriction Rules

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below Screenshot , there are no permission when you sign up Financial Service Cloud Developer Edition org

[image][![Please check][2]][2]